# Styling for only the first column in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

In Drupal, I have a table node that gets generated from mysql user data.

The elements are structured as follows:

```
<table>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <td>
  </tr
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How would I go about targeting the first `td` in each `tr` using CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just using

```
tr td:first-child { ... }
```

the support of `:first-child` includes all modern browser, even IE7